# Iterator error value

Tags: c++, list, search, error-handling

whats a value that is generally used as an error value besides `<container>.end()`? im doing a simple linear search through a `std::list<int>`and i want a way to know that the search did not turn up a place in the list

Comment: Why isn't `end` good enough?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of the standard C++ classes return `<container>.end()` when a search result fails since `end()` doesn't actually point to an element in the container (it points "past-the-end" of the container).  I don't see a reason why another type would be necessary.

Answer (score 3):

> i want a way to know that the search did not turn up a place in the list

[std::find](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/find.html) is helpful for the task.